# floating errors on ios devices "A server with the specified hostname could not be found"

Tags: ios, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

A multiplatform project has an error:

```
"Error Domain=KotlinException Code=0 "Exception in http request: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSUnderlyingError=0x28052d1d0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1003 "(null)" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorNWPathKey=satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: pdp_ip0, ipv4, dns, expensive, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <D1AC7328-3E88-40AE-B432-D8ED35C4DED8>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    LocalDataTask <D1AC7328-3E88-40AE-B432-D8ED35C4DED8>.<1>
), NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://oneclick.tmweb.ru/medhelp_main/v1/login, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://oneclick.tmweb.ru/medhelp_main/v1/login, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12}" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Exception in http request: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSUnderlyingError=0x28052d1d0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1003 "(null)" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorNWPathKey=satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: pdp_ip0, ipv4, dns, expensive, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <D1AC7328-3E88-40AE-B432-D8ED35C4DED8>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
   LocalDataTask <D1AC7328-3E88-40AE-B432-D8ED35C4DED8>.<1>
), NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://oneclick.tmweb.ru/medhelp_main/v1/login, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://oneclick.tmweb.ru/medhelp_main/v1/login, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12}, KotlinException=io.ktor.client.engine.darwin.DarwinHttpRequestException: Exception in http request: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSUnderlyingError=0x28052d1d0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1003 "(null)" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorNWPathKey=satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: pdp_ip0, ipv4, dns, expensive, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <D1AC7328-3E88-40AE-B432-D8ED35C4DED8>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    LocalDataTask <D1AC7328-3E88-40AE-B432-D8ED35C4DED8>.<1>
), NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://oneclick.tmweb.ru/medhelp_main/v1/login, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://oneclick.tmweb.ru/medhelp_main/v1/login, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12}, KotlinExceptionOrigin=}"
```

There is a connection with Internet providers (someone has no problems, and someone constantly gets them), but other applications on the phone work fine

Initialization and request

```
fun getHttpClient(): HttpClient{

    val httpClient1 = HttpClient(){

install(ContentNegotiation) {

            json(kotlinx.serialization.json.Json {

ignoreUnknownKeys = true

            })

        }

install(HttpTimeout) {

requestTimeoutMillis = 60000

            connectTimeoutMillis = 60000

            socketTimeoutMillis = 60000

        }

}

return httpClient1

}

@Throws(Exception::class)  suspend fun doLoginApiCall(signature: String, username: String, password: String): UserList {

    val resp : UserList = getHttpClient().use**{** client ->

client.post(BASE_URL_LOCAL + "login") {

headers {

append(AUTH, LocalEndPoint.API_KEY)

            }

val tmp = MultiPartFormDataContent(formData {

append(USERNAME, username)

                append(PASSWORD, password)

                append(HASH, signature)

            })

            setBody(tmp)

        }

.body()

    }

return resp

}
```

Call in from iOS

```
sdk.doLoginApiCall(signature: sig ,username: login!, password:pass!, completionHandler: { response, error in

                if let res : UserList = response {

                } else {

                }

            })
```

How can I get rid of this error

Apparently due to the fact that the project does not include a Mac version, the sandbox is hidden. Registered outgoing connections in the entitlements file